# How do I fetch a relationship of a relationship in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have 3 entities:

Building, Floors, and Rooms

The relationship is as follows:

Building -> Floors -> Rooms

Building -> Floors is a To-Many relationship
Floors -> Rooms is a To-Many Relationship

How would I go about fetching the data within Rooms?

I know how to fetch Building -> Floors with the predicate code below but how do I go a step further and fetch the data of Rooms?

let fetchFloorPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "buildingOfFloor.buildingName == %@", buildingName)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a predicate to fetch relationships, a relationship is also a property in your entity with the same name as you named the relationship in Xcode.

So if you have a Building object `building` and the relationship to Floors is named floors you get all Floors object that belong to a building using

```
let floors = building.floors
```

or if you want it as an Array instead of a Set

```
let floors = Array(building.floors)
```

and the same goes for Rooms if we assume the name of the relationship is rooms

```
let rooms = floor.rooms
```